# How to dispose of an unmounted Widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am writing a flutter app and if you already started it once, I dont want the user to see the Intro Screen again

In my MaterialApp:

```
home: firstStart ? DeviceSelection() : StartScreen()
```

firstStart is a boolean, if it is the first start, it should start the App with the StartScreen() and if its not, it should go straight to DeviceSelection(). That all works fine, but my problem is the following error:

> Error: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
> Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.

I think it starts StartScreen too, even if firstStart is false, because it has to get its value out of the shared preferences, because I see it pop up shortly sometimes.

I already tried some stuff I found, like writing a dispose method:

```
@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
}
```

or

```
if (!mounted) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

in a method that I call after the screen starts, but it doesnt work either. Any ideas what I could do to get rid of this error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

mb set a flag, like:

```
bool lookedIntro = false; // if user look it first
```

and then use:

```
@override
void initState() {
  // take data flag from database or somewhere else (file)
  // and check it
}
```

and also read about initState() [more](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html)